# Getting "An item with the same key has already been added" Error when I try to create a new client secret via AzAD module

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-powershell

I'm quite puzzled. I'm trying to use powershell to create a new client secret for an Azure application. I'm hitting the error "An item with the same key has already been added" but there's currently no client secret assigned to the application. Any ideas would be great.

```
Connect-AzAccount

 $sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "TS-Test-14-Oct-2021"
 
 $start = Get-Date -Format "o"
 $end = (Get-Date).AddYears(1) | Get-Date -Format "o"
 $Guid = (New-guid).toString()


$Password = @{
displayName= 'Hi'
endDateTime= $end
hint= 'NIL'
keyId= "$Guid"
secretText= 'xxxx'
startDateTime= $start
}

New-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId $sp.Id -PasswordCredentials $Password
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code and facing the same issue

You can try with this code:

```
$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddYears(3)
$aadAppsecret01 = New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId ObjectId CustomKeyIdentifier "Secret01" -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi ShrutiJoshi-MT. I see that your code does work. However, I have a requirement to assign the application a customized password instead of a randomly generated one. Any ideas?

Comment: we cannot set all the details while creating a AD app secret like `hint` , `keyid` and `secretText` . We can only mention the `display name` and `start date` and `end date `.

Comment: If answer helps, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you